# go with sqlx NamedQuery timestamp works with date but not with datetime. NamedQuery vs Query

Tags: sql, go, nullpointerexception, sqlx

```
rows, err := db.NamedQuery(`SELECT ts FROM test_table WHERE ts > '1999-01-08 04:05:06';`, map[string]interface{}{})
```

The code above gave me the following error:

```
unexpected `:` while reading named param at 74
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

This is strange, as the following snippet,

```
rows, err := db.NamedQuery(`SELECT ts FROM test_table WHERE ts > '1999-01-08';`, map[string]interface{}{})
```

runs without fault.
The difference between the two, is adding time to the input.

I resorted to using `db.Query` instead of the sqlx method `db.NamedQuery` which solved my problem.

I now see that I should have passed my input to NamedQuery as a parameter.
How does one typically write such a query and why would you use NamedQuery rather than Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why would you use NamedQuery rather than Query?

Queries that use named parameters are easier for the human to parse.

> How does one typically write such a query

```golang
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
ts, err := time.Parse(layout, "1999-01-08 04:05:06")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

arg := map[string]interface{}{"ts": ts}
rows, err := db.NamedQuery(`SELECT ts FROM test_table WHERE ts > :ts`, arg)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```